# Linkedin OAuth2: access-token is instantly expired

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I would like to do social-login with LinkedIn. I am using the very convenient package react-social-login (see demo here : https://deepakaggarwal7.github.io/react-social-login/).

In the demo, and in my implementation, everything works fine, and I am able to retrieve the access-token and expiration-date.

Unfortunately, for LinkedIn, the access-token is instantly expired. You can even test it in the demo.

My question is: do you also retrieve expired access-token ? Is it related to some configuration in LinkedIn API (according to the documentation it expires after 60 days) ?

Many thanks for your help,

Nicolas

Comment: This seems like a question suited for the creators of the API or the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

so im quite certain that you are talking to a V2 API from linkedin? if this is the case. then your access token is just fine.

the problem with linkedin's API is that a part of it (V2) is just for the partners of linkedin. you can become a partner by requesting it. but it will take you up to a month.

the V1 api is completely free to use after you authenticated a user.

if this is not the case, please provide more information about how you came to the conclussion that the authentication token you get is allways expired. because technically this isnt possible because the linkedin service generates one at the fly.